# spark structured streaming: parquet partition name uniqueness

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming

While streaming from Kafka using Spark Structured stream 2.1, with partitionBy a string column(containing a string of a date in this format yyyy-mm-dd), I expected one

```
interval27e/_spark_metadata
interval27e/interval_read_date=2010-10-27 08%3A02%3A48
interval27e/interval_read_date=2010-10-30 04%3A27%3A34
interval27e/interval_read_date=2010-11-03 02%3A22%3A13
interval27e/interval_read_date=2010-11-03 07%3A27%3A08
interval27e/interval_read_date=2010-11-14 08%3A37%3A52
interval27e/interval_read_date=2010-11-19 01%3A46%3A50
```

Spark is appending strings ("08%3A02%3A48") with multiple directories per date.

This is the writeStream command:

```
interval3=interval2     \
  .writeStream 
  .format("parquet") 
  .option("path","/user/usera/interval27e") 
  .partitionBy("interval_read_date") 
  .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds') 
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/usera/checkpoint27e") 
  .start()
```

I dont observe this happening on other stackOverflow questions concerning writing parquet with partitioning.

How can I write the partition the parquet directories without that string being appended to the directory name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `interval_read_date` is not data / date-like string at all but timestamp. `%3A` [is percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) `:` therefore names you have are:

```
interval_read_date=2010-10-27 08:02:48
interval_read_date=2010-10-30 04:27:34
...
```

Please double check you're using the right data and truncate or cast if necessary.